# graphics card / computer cant detect dvi monitor

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, graphics-card, dvi

my monitor is not being detected by my computer.
this problem has come after i updated my graphics card drivers. my card is an old gtx 460 and its drivers had never been updated and so were at 258.something so ive updated them to 332.21 (still not the latest i know) but after the update the monitor wasnt displaying anything, so using a remote desktop application, i realised the computer was thinking its display was vga, how do i manually change it to dvi?

thanks in advance

Comment: The first step, remove the display drivers, what happens then?

Comment: then the monitor works at 800x600... do i reinstall the drivers? or should i find a specific monitor driver? what do i do now?

Comment: You can try installing the monitor driver.  Does Winows detect a generic or specific monitor?

Comment: neither, its really strange, in "printers and devices" there isn't a monitor there, ill download the drivers from the lg website and then try and install them

Comment: ok so when that didn't work i did a system restore and reinstalled the very latest drivers (340.52 released 2 weeks ago) and now it recognises that annoying "generic php monitor" -.- ive downloaded and tried to update the drivers but it says "windows detected the drivers are at the latest version", how do i fix this anyone?

Comment: **You need to be specific when you say something doesn't work.**

Comment: srry, either way now my problem has changed to the generic non pnp monitor problem so i am done for this thread, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try going to the menu on the monitor and scroll through and find the option to change it. I just updated to the latest one, 340.xx,so you do have some old drivers.The Nvidia.com offers an automatic search for the right drivers.Hope it helps